# UITableviewCell stuck scrolling while set height zero dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have JSON object where one key is interface_id and I want to set Cell height accordingly, When I try to set height 0, after that tableView stuck while scrolling.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
   if (dataArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "interface_id") as! Int == 1{
     return 0
   }else{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried changing `heightForRowAt` instead of `estimatedHeightForRowAt`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: doest it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to use self sizing cells, for the `UITableView` you will set an estimated row height, and also set the rowHeight to a value of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. so changing the Cell height for row your code should be look like that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44.0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (dataArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "interface_id") as! Int == 1{
        return 0
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```